# Photoshop select and mask tool are not working properly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

Last week they worked properly, I could select and mask with the brush tool and the quick selection tool, then one day it started glitching when I kept the left button pressed and couldn't select with precision.

Other thing I noted is that before I could easily select what was under the crosshair, and now whenever I can select anything, it does from one edge of the circle to the other.

I already did the reset preferences and reset brush troubleshooting.

Comment: We can't really troubleshoot local technical issues here. They are off topic. All you'd get is the standard, reset prefs, tools, reboot.. etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "local technical issues"? isn't what this forum is for?

Comment: It is not for tech support issues. Those should be referred to the developer, in this case Adobe.

Comment: Local technical issues -- i.e. a problem on **your** system, in **your** environment - not an all-user application issue. And this isn't a "forum" at all `:)` it's a Q&A site about *design* not tech support.

Comment: @caerxhan Please consult the [Help] and specifically the [On Topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article. We are neither a forum, nor are we the place to turn to with technical issues (even if they are regarding design software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the tool in the top menu bar, click on the downward arrow. This will open a dialog that shows size, hardness and spacing. You spacing may be set too high. Bring it down to about 20%. Play with that setting and see if it affects the selection area.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Turns out it was a combination of spacing + the smooth slider + restarting the software after all